# after converting powershell script to .exe listbox index is not working

Tags: powershell, indexing, textbox, listbox

I have created a script for list the names in the listbox which is given as input in the textbox. It works fine while am running in the Powershell ISE. But after i did converting to .exe files now if add any input via textbox the same which is supposed to be displayed in the listbox is not happenning.
Anyone could help on this?

I did converting process by using PS2EXE application and its method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A a sample code snippet is required for better solutions.

The PS2EXE does not provide a standalone-independent file that can be run without Powershell, because the tool in itself is a PowerShell script which does the in-memory compilation and generates the EXE file.

P.S:  There is also a chance that the functionality of such EXE files may be impacted as well.

You can look up this link for more information : 
[Microsoft-Technet- PS2EXE](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PS2EXE-GUI-Convert-e7cb69d5)

Comment: thank you @clint
as am a beginner... its really helped for me.